# Excel: Find out which cells access one specific cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I work on a complex Excel file with worksheets (tabs). I have to move one cell due to adding other things and and want to find out what the consequences are. But I do not want to check all the other cells in the other worksheets.

Is there a possibility to find out in Excel what other cells (in other worksheets) access one specific cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cell you are planning to move, then click "Trace Dependents" on the Formulas tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, "trace dependents" what you need.

However if you move your cell (by cut & paste or drag & drop) all the references will be updated to the new location.

Neither of above options work when your cell is referenced indirectly (by INDIRECT or OFFSET function)